# Is there a Keyboard Shortcut in Chrome Developer Tools to switch Source File?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Checking the list

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts?csw=1#sources-panel

I cannot find any way to navigate through the source files inside Chrome Dev Tools. Anyone with an idea how to switch source files without using the mouse?

Comment: If it's not there it probably dosen't exist.

Comment: yes, might not exist, but it is a highly surprising omission IMHO. Since this is about developer tools, I do not consider it a superuser question. Surprised about the downvote.

Comment: not giving up as quick as user2456. there might be configurable commands for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no keyboard shortcut for doing this. I would know since I have recently updated that page multiple times to add or change some shortcuts.

I'm pretty sure there's no command you can configure either.

I'd suggest [opening a ticket](http://crbug.com) for it if you would like to see this added.

Comment: thx, issue at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=296876&q=thulka&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: ^ FYI that issue has been merged into https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226194 so star that one instead

Answer (score 9):

`Ctrl-P` / `Ctrl-O` shortcut will bring up a Goto-Source dialog.

Comment: yes! this was also mentioned in the issue (see above) comment: "As a workaround, you can use Ctrl+O and type in file name or select tab with arrows. Top items in that list are your tabs." wanted to add this here anyway-

Comment: getting back to this after a while: this woraround is pretty good.

Comment: Yaas, not quite as good as most IDE navigation but so helpful for large projects.